# Applying 802.11 in ns2.34

Tags: ns2, wifi

I wanted to ask if anyone can help me out in steps about how can I apply IEEE 802.11 MAC protocol for my TCL file in ns2.34. I have my tcl network done but do not have any idea how to apply 802.11 protocol.

Answer (score 0):

---

Mac 802.11 is the default MAC type in ns2. The most simulation files have a line like ...

```
set val(mac)     Mac/802_11            ;#MAC type
```

or

```
set opt(mac)     Mac/802_11            ;# MAC type
```

---